# Windows credential provider. How do i get the authentication result?

Tags: windows, credential-providers

New to stackoverflow so please bear with me.
We've written a fully functional credential provider but still need some assistance. Currently the credential provider works by performing and online authentication against our servers. If the authentication is successful THEN the local windows authentication occurs. Now we want the credential provider to work the other way around.. perform local authentication first, if that is successful THEN go online and authenticate against the servers. Any ideas on how to achieve this? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `LogonUser` to authenticate a user.

Comment: Thank you.. Will look into that